# Have foreign_key on mongoid

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3

Well I'm have a `PerformerSource` and `MonthlyEarning` documents which has a field called `performer_id`

```
class PerformerSource
  ....
  field :performer_id,:type => Integer
  ....
  ....
end


class MonthlyEarning
  ....
  field :performer_id,:type => Integer
  ....
  ....
end
```

Now all I want to set a `has_many` relationships between the two documents with performer_id in mind i.e

```
  performer_source has_many monthly_earnings
  monthly_earning belongs_to performer_source
```

I think the following isn't allowed in Mongoid  because apparently when I set the relationships
 it just does not return anything

But if it does then please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this work so the idea was to have relations through performer_id field present in both document so all that is need is

to set this

```
class PerformerSource
  ....
  field :performer_id,:type => Integer
  ....
  ....
  has_many :earnings ,:class_name => "MonthlyEarning",:primary_key => :performer_id,:foreign_key => :performer_id
end

class MonthlyEarning
   ....
  field :performer_id,:type => Integer
  ....
  ....
  belongs_to :performer,:class_name => "PerformerSource",:primary_key => :performer_id,:foreign_key => :performer_id
end
```

The way it works over here is the `:primary_key` i.e(`performer_id`) when firing the request through association

This is exactly what I want